# Javascript save/restore Widgets on several clients

Tags: javascript, json, database, vue.js, widget

i plan to implement a webapp that allows users to **add widgets** that are predefined by me in something like a menu (e.g. two buttons and a card with some content) to something like a canvas. 
I then want to **save this layout** so it can be later restored on the **same device as well as on an other device**. 
There should also be a fast way of deciding on one device to add one widget to a layout that is shown on another device right now. This addition i made from one device should be **visible on the other device instantely**.

I thought about how to do this but am unsure, I saw some stuff about saving it in databases or in json format like in this example with react https://www.storyblok.com/tp/react-dynamic-component-from-json. 
As I am a beginner, I with vue.js as well as json etc I am quite unsure on how to decide how to implement such a functionality. 
For example with a database/json file I am unsure on how the other device will receive that something was added by another device.

I am glad on any tips or suggestions.

Comment: As soon as you want something to persist from one device to another, you'd have to use some sort of backend so the information can be exchanged. It is a bit of a broad question you ask here, but basically you can use AJAX requests that send data to a backend endpoint (like `POST myapi.com/users/someconfig`), and request it in another app through the use of polling (like calling `GET myapi.com/users/someconfig` every 5 seconds). There are other solutions that work instantly (sockets) but its harder to implement.

Comment: thank you for your response, even though my question is so vague, that already made it a big clearer for me! :) just so i understand correctly: this backend endpoint then could have a connection to a e.g. a database, right? Or i can post some json code and then just get it directly from there with a get request?

Comment: Yes you need to persist it in a database; imagine it being 2 separate requests (1 to save in client A, 1 to retrieve in client B) which have no state in common. So when the second request asks your webserver for the data, your webserver gets it from the database which should give you the data from the first request. One low-fi solution is to use SQLite, but MySQL is a more robust solution. Also, you can do it without having a database which brings us to the sockets implementation, which is like a continuous connection between 2 clients. You would still need a db if you want it to be resumable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now i have a better idea what to look into. :)